# reading a 3 dimensional array from txt file

Tags: c, arrays, 3d

I am having a problem storing a 3 dimensional array into a proper format. 
The text file reads as follows:

```
4 3   5 4   3 2
3 5   4 3   2 3
1 0   4 3   2 4
2 3
1 5
1 6
3 5
```

the integers are standard integers and need to be arranged as they appear. So the upper part of the txt file will be stored into a 3x3 matrix with each cell containing the two integer individual values. the bottom values should be stored in a 1x4 matrix with each cell containing the 2 individual integer values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You need to show us what you've tried.  We'll help you fix an honest attempt to solve the problem, but we won't simply write the code for you.

Comment: You talk about a 3x3 array — that is a 2D array, not a 3D array.  How are you supposed to store each pair?  Are these complex integers of the form x+iy?  How are you supposed to know the size of the matrices?  Does the 1x4 matrix need to be 2D with a degenerate dimension, or is it sufficient to create a vector (1D array)?  Both are possible; the degenerate array dimension may be necessary, but might not be.  You say 'sorted'; does that have any meaning beyond 'placed' or 'read'?  Or is it really a 3x3x2 matrix (which is a 3D matrix)?  Is that a 1x4x2 matrix — ditto?

Comment: "I am having a problem storing " --> post that code.

Comment: You've edited the question, but you've not explained whether the pairs should be in `struct pair { int x; int y; };` or in two elements of the third dimension of an array, or by some other mechanism.  You've also not shown what you've tried.  What you've tried is important because it helps us calibrate an answer to your apparent level of expertise.  Are the 3x3 and 1x4 sizes fixed?  From what you've said, yes.